# EPPlus to use YIELD Excel in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm using the latest EPPlus version in my application .NET, to invoke the YIELD function but my return values are always like `#VALUE`

My code:

```
var workSheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
workSheet1.Cells["A1"].Value = new DateTime(2021, 04, 13);
workSheet1.Cells["A2"].Value = new DateTime(2021, 04, 15);
workSheet1.Cells["A3"].Value = 0.0385;
workSheet1.Cells["A4"].Value = 100.07;
workSheet1.Cells["A5"].Value = 100;
workSheet1.Cells["A6"].Value = 1;
workSheet1.Cells["A7"].Value = 2;
workSheet1.Cells["A8"].Formula = ("YIELD(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)");
workSheet1.Cells["A8"].Calculate();
           
object result01 = workSheet1.Cells["A8"].Value;
```

but when I open my Excel file:

[image: Image from my Excel]

I need use this function in my code, I already try use ASPOSE, SPIRE, but it always has some difference between this lib and calling the function directly in Excel.
No I'm do some tests with EPPlus, but I'm with this problem.

Comment: Please **don't post pictures of code here.**  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, I edited this.

Comment: Can I confirm what is the problem? Are you expecting cells A1, A2 to be displayed as date formatted? Are cells A3 to A7 formatted correctly in your excel screenshot? Are you expecting a different value for cell A8?

Comment: cells A1 and A2 is correct! my problem is the value for cell A8.
In my code is returned '{#VALUE}' and in Excel returned -0,859.

Comment: Is your EPPlus the latest commercial version 5.x ? Or the latest free version under LGPL 4.x ?

Comment: The reason I am clarifying on which version you are using is because the "latest" free version does not have the yield feature. The functions supported in different versions are here: https://epplussoftware.com/en/Developers/FormulaCalc

Comment: Thank you for share this link with supported functions, but I'm using the latest comercial version 5.x.

Comment: We appreciate if you could post your issue with sample code (using Aspose.Cells) and sample files in Aspose.Cells forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9), we will check and fix the issue to match with MS Excel results soon.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Ah Ok. I will do that!